# Insects emerging from vertical tube

Tags: entomology

I found a vertical mud tube about the thickness of a pencil in my garden with a series of metallic green insects coming out of it. They came out when I pulled a weed but stopped when I stopped, as if the vibrations were scaring them out. I think they were bees, wasps, or flies. They were 1/2" long or a little longer and thin. Head, thorax, and abdomen were all shiny green, wings transparent. What are they?

I live near Philadelphia and it was in the upper 60s F today.

Comment: Did you happen to take a picture of them?

Comment: alas, no camera available

Answer (score 3):

Mud tube, metallic green, bee-like - sounds like a mason bee to me.

There are several metallic green mason bees (*Osmia* spp.). As [Wikipedia explains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mason_bee):

> Mason bees are named for their habit of using mud or other “masonry”
>   products in constructing their nests, which are made in naturally
>   occurring gaps such as between cracks in stones or other small dark
>   cavities; when available some species preferentially use hollow stems
>   or holes in wood made by wood-boring insects.

One example here:

[image]
Photos at http://www.laspilitas.com/insects/megachilidae/osmia-mason-bee.html